# How to install PCL on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, pcloud

```
CMake Error at cv_utils/CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindPCL.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "PCL", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "PCL" with any of
  the following names:

    PCLConfig.cmake
    pcl-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "PCL" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "PCL_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "PCL" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ahmad/Desktop/Layered Scene Decomposition/LayeredSceneDecomposition-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441189/locations-pclconfig-cmake-and-pcl-config-cmake-files-for-pcl-library

Comment: "See also "/home/ahmad/Desktop/Layered Scene Decomposition/LayeredSceneDecomposition-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log"."

Answer (score 5):

Answering quite late, however for the reference of others who might be facing the same problem.

PCL is available in default ubuntu-18.04 packages and can be installed using aptitude package manage.

```
sudo apt install libpcl-dev
```

refer following github issue: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/2739

Answer (score 0):

Most of the things have been already said in the previous answers. I would like to add that if you want to know more details on the installation or just about the PCL library itself, you should look at the official website of the PCL Library.

You can find it here:

https://pointclouds.org/

and installation for linux (related to the question of the OP) can be found here:

https://pointclouds.org/downloads/#linux

Some tutorials can be found here:

https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/master/